# Validating form data Javascript

Tags: jquery, validation

So I am trying to set up form validation for two forms I have on a page, only one of which is visible at a time.  While one form is visible (display = 'inline') the other form is hidden (display = 'none').

I am hooking into the forms 'submit' event and returning 'false' so that I can validate the form fields before submitting the form manually.

The issue I run into is when I try to make the code modular, i.e. trying to set up the form behavior on both forms using common methods.  When I try to do that I cannot get the form to not submit upon the click of the submit button.  However, when I set up both forms individualy (duplicate methods that do the exact same thing, just using different DOM objects) I can get the functionality to work.

Below is my attempt to loop through two arrays that create the DOM objects within the method as they are passed in:

```
if($('#payment_wrapper').length > 0){
    var form_elements = [['#nr_form', '#nr_submit_button', '#nr_notes',     
'#nr_amount'],['#rec_form', '#rec_submit_button', '#rec_notes', '#nr_amount']];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        setupForms(form_elements[i]);
    }
}

    function setupForms(arr){
        $(arr[0]).submit(function(event) {
            (arr[1]).prop('disabled', true);
            validateForm(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
            return false;
        });
    }

    function validateForm(form, button, notes, amount){
        var err = false;
        var note = $(button).val().length
        var payment = $(amount).val();
        if(note > 150){
            alert("note is greater than 150");
            $('.payment_errors').text("It seems that your note is too long.  Please make sure it is 150 characters of less")
            $(button).prop('disabled', false);
            err = true; 
        } else if (!validateAmount(payment, button)){
            err = true;
        } else if ( err == false){
            $(form).get(0).submit();
        }
    }

    function validateAmount(payment, submit_button){
        var match = payment.match(/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}/)
        if (payment.length == 0) {
            $('.payment_errors').text("You must enter a valid amount before submitting")
            $(submit_button).prop('disabled', false);
            return false;
        } else if (!match) {
            $('.payment_errors').text("Hmmmm, something is wrong with your payment amount.  Make sure your amount is in the proper format")
            $(submit_button).prop('disabled', false);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;    
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Save yourself some headaches and just use [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Comment: Any reason you can't use jquery validate plugin instead writing your own solution? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation; Also you will get help quicker if you put your javascript and markup in js fiddle.

Comment: No reason in particular that I don't use the plugin.  More just trying to understand this particular case.  What do you mean by headaches?  Is what I am trying to do harder to implement than the plugin?  If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
event.preventDefault();
```

before returning false.

Comment: When using jQuery, there's no need to do both.  Also, [jQuery's `preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) is not exactly the same as `preventDefault()` with pure JavaScript alone.  Also, `preventDefault()` should be the first item in a function, unlike `return false` which is the last.